# In my firebase push notification sometimes notification image is received sometimes not

Tags: node.js, express, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am sending firebase push notification using firebase-admin package, my tech stack is nodejs@14.21, expressjs and mongodb. I am sending notification 6500 users approx, but some users are receiving notification image sometime and sometime not. My notification image is hosted in imgur public url, which is 36kb in size and png format.

[image]

below is my code

```
const MasterUser = require("../models/user");
const TransNotification = require("../models/notification");

const async = require("async");

const firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("../config/ThinkZoneAppServiceAccount.json");

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const genericImg = "https://i.imgur.com/8YEceQ6.png";

const sliceIntoChunks = (arr) => {
  let chunkSize = 499;
  const newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
    const chunk = arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
    newArr.push(chunk);
  }
  return newArr;
};

const sendNotifMultiCast = async (notifData) => {
  const sentUsers = notifData.length;
  const { title, body, image, navigateto } = notifData[0];

  let deliveredUsers = 0;
  let failedUsers = 0;

  await TransNotification.insertMany(notifData);

  const tokensArr = sliceIntoChunks(notifData.map((el) => el.token));

  async.forEach(
    tokensArr,
    (tokensChunk, callback) => {
      const payload = {
        notification: { title, body, image },
        data: { navigateto },
        tokens: tokensChunk,
      };

      firebaseAdmin
        .messaging()
        .sendMulticast(payload)
        .then((resp) => {
          const { successCount, failedCount } = resp;

          deliveredUsers += successCount;
          failedUsers += failedCount;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log("notif err===>>>", err));

      callback();
    },
    (err) =>
      console.log(
        `notifLog===>>> sentUsers=${sentUsers}, deliveredUsers=${deliveredUsers}, failedUsers=${failedUsers}`
      )
  );
};

const tchGenericNotif = (req, res) => {
  const query = [
    { $match: { $expr: { $and: [{ $eq: ["$usertype", "fellow"] }] } } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "pushnotification_tokenids",
        let: { userid: "$userid" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ["$userid", "$$userid"] },
                  { $not: { $in: ["$token", ["", undefined, null]] } },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          { $project: { _id: 0, token: 1 } },
        ],
        as: "tokenData",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$tokenData" } },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        userid: 1,
        token: "$tokenData.token",
      },
    },
  ];

  MasterUser.aggregate(query)
    .then(async (userData) => {
      const notifData = userData.map((el) => {
        return {
          ...el,
          title: "generic notif title",
          body: "generic notif body",
          image: genericImg,
          navigateto: "/dashboard",
          extraNotifData: {},
        };
      });

      sendNotifMultiCast(notifData);

      res
        .status(200)
        .send({ msg: `${notifData.length} msg sent successfully.` });
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(200).send({ err: err.message }));
};

module.exports = {
  tchGenericNotif,
};
```

I am expecting that all users should receive notification with notification image. Same user receives notification image sometime but sometime not, and some users are not receiving notification image.

Comment: Which version of FCM SDK are you using?